# unable to import cython generated .so in python

Tags: python, cython

I've searched many discusses on the `ImportError: No module named` error, but seems no one can solve my problems, so please allow me to ask again.

Here is my package folder structure:

```
/modules
├── build
│   ├── lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
│   │   └── Package
│   │       ├── __init__.so
│   │       ├── SendTraffic.so
│   │       └── Utils.so
│   └── temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
│       └── Package
│           ├── __init__.o
│           ├── SendTraffic.o
│           └── Utils.o
├── Package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── SendTraffic.c
│   ├── SendTraffic.py
│   ├── SendTraffic.pyc
│   ├── Utils.c
│   ├── Utils.py
│   └── Utils.pyc
├── setup.py
```

and setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import os

os.environ['CFLAGS']="-s -O2"

setup(
    name = 'Hello world app',
    ext_modules = cythonize("Package/*.py"),
)
```

It can build the .so files successfully. but when I import them under `/modules/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7` :

```
/modules/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
>>> import Package.SendTraffic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Package.SendTraffic
```

Inside the Package folder, I can import them successfully:

```
/modules/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/Package$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import SendTraffic
>>>
```

I've also tried add `/modules/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7` into sys.path, but not work. use `setup.py install` to install them into system-wide package folder also doesn't work.

Could someone help me to import Package.SendTraffic successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've figure out the answer.

In the package folder, `__init__.so` is not accepted by python, it needs `__init__.py` file

Comment: Is that a blank `__init__.py`?